Largest number of different eigenvalues of $f_A (B) = A \star B$
$A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{R}^n)$
$(A \star B)_{ij} = \begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      (AB)_{ij}, i(mod \ 2) = 1\\
      b_{ij}, i(mod \ 2) = 0
    \end{cases}\,.
\end{equation} $
For matrix A we define the operator $f_A : M_n(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R}^n) $ according to the rule $f_A (B) = A \star B$
What is the largest number of different eigenvalues such an operator can have (for a fixed n)?
Here are some of my thoughts:
$A \star B = \lambda B$ (1)
First of all:
$b_{ij} = \lambda b_{ij}$ if $i(mod \ 2) = 0$ (2)
It means that $b_{ij} = 0$ if $i(mod \ 2) = 0$. So, even rows and columns of $A \star B$ are zero vectors. From (1) we get system of equations:
$a_{i1} * b_{11}  + ... + a_{in} * b_{n1} = \lambda b_{11}$ for $i = 1,3...n$
So, minimum dimension of the solution space here is $n/2$.
There are $n/2$ of such systems of equations (look at (2)), it means that total dimension of the solution space is $n^2/4$. It means that number of eigenvalues is $n^2/(n^2 /4) = 4 $
I am not sure if everything is alright.

What stops you from taking A and B to be diagonal matrices with distinct  (from any other entries on either of the diagonals) prime entries on each diagonal, out of curiosity?

@J.Dmaths if you are talking about diagonalisation, not every matrix could be diagonalised

No, JD was suggesting to take $B$ to be diagonal with large entries  and then use something like Grieshgorin circles.
